# Manga about a boy summoned to a fantasy world, but with low stats. Betrayed and kicked into dungeon

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character got summoned with his classmates, but his level was zero and they send him to a town to do agriculture. There was a nearby dungeon that extremely powerful that no one had ever reported coming back from. His classmates and his friends throw him inside of it.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: :) Since you posted another question, a reminder that you have an answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

As per...

- [Manga where a guy, his childhood best friend and (I think) three other guys get transferred to another world. And the MC has 10 skill slots](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245101/manga-where-a-guy-his-childhood-best-friend-and-i-think-three-other-guys-get),

... could this be *[The Dungeon Seeker](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-dungeon-seeker)*?

[image: Front cover of The Dungeon Seeker]

> Junpei Takeda, a high school student, is childhood friends with Noriko Tatsumiya and the bully Kido Shouta. One day, during the usual course of bullying Junpei, they were suddenly summoned to a different world by the whim of "God". Summoned Heroes with cheats, or so he thought. But it turns out Junpei's stats were even worse than an average farmer. Tricked into a deathly labyrinth by the only one he trust, he walks the journey for revenge.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]