# Manga about a boy betrayed by his friends and pushed into a cave to die

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The basic plot from what I remember involves the main character and three of his friends (one girl and two guys) teleporting to another world. They all become farmers of sorts and the world has a leveling system.

In this world, there is a cave full of monsters said to be impossible to survive. They all betray him and shove him into the pit/cave thing. He only survives via a magical orb guy that tells him how to fight the monsters. He ends up making it out alive and meets the guy that helped him as well as a girl.

I think he also seeks revenge on his ex-friends.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***[The Dungeon Seeker](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=133843)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Junpei Takeda, a high school student, is childhood friends with Noriko Tatsumiya and the bully Kido Shouta. One day, during the usual course of bullying Junpei, they were suddenly summoned to a different world by the whim of "God". Summoned Heroes with cheats, or so he thought. But it turns out Junpei's stats were even worse than an average farmer. Tricked into a deathly labyrinth by the only one he trusts, he walks the journey for revenge.

A high school student named Junpei is summoned to another world, along with four male classmates who've been bullying him, and his childhood friend, Noriko. They end up being labelled as trash by the king in the other world, and banished from the capital to a remote farming village.

There's a dungeon near the village, to which the villagers must regularly offer sacrifices, and Junpei is subsequently betrayed by Noriko and thrown into it by the bullies. Inside, he happens upon a small, rectangular slate, which projects an image of a previous adventurer, who offers advice on how to escape the dungeon alive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If accepted, of course, it will be a dupe of [your answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245101/manga-where-a-guy-his-childhood-best-friend-and-i-think-three-other-guys-get?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. Thank you!